# boost::next and std::next equivalent?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, stl, iterator

I have a requirement where I want to peek into next iterator position to see if it is the end of container. I can not use `std::next` as C++11 is not yet adopted. Can I use `boost::next` as an exact alternative? Thanks

Comment: Much of the new C++11 features in the standard library was modeled after their Boost equivalents. So without looking at any documentation I would say that it should work.

Comment: [boost::next](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#functions_next_prior) vs [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next). So yes.

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What does the documentation say?

Comment: @gx_ that's the best answer here. A shame it is a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be surprised if it doesn't work as expected. If in doubt, you can always use [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

```
some_container c;
some_container::iterator it;
std::advance(it, 1);
bool b = it == c.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

No in general. Probably yes if you use it for iterators (which is the assumed use anyway).

The reason I say no in general is because, if the argument class is not an iterator there is a substitution error in `std::next` (`iterator_traits<...>`) in the second (default) argument. So things that used to work with `boost::next` may not work with `std::next` anymore.

For example, I used to use `boost::next` for classes that are not iterators but have the `operator++` defined (but not the binary + operator). Often I want to generate the next element and the `boost::next` was perfect for that.

```
struct myint{
  int impl;
  myint& operator++(){impl++; return *this;}
}
```

`boost::next` works with this class but `std::next` doesn't. So, I have to stick to make a copy and increment or fall back to `boost::next` (or even worst, generate an `iterator_trait` for something that is not an iterator).

My problem with `std::next` is that the second argument (related to `difference_type`) imposes an unnecessary restriction on the argument. But I might be the one that is wrong by abusing the function `::next`.

Comment: OP is specifically talking about using it for iterators

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated a code base to c++11 and the latest boost. I updated boost::next to std::next (the opposite of what you want) to no negative effect.

So the likely answer is yes.